# Передача динамическое таблицы в виде массива

Tags: php

Создаем динамическую таблицу:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style>
#tbl {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
#tbl td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 4px;
}
#tbl input {
    width: 50px;
}
a.delRow, #addRow {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#addRow').click(function() {
        var t = $('#tbl');
        t.find('tr')
         .eq(1)
         .clone()
         .appendTo(t)
         .find('td:last')
         .append('<a class="delRow">удалить</a>')
         .end()
         .find('input')
         .val('');
    });
    $('#tbl').on('click', 'a.delRow', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="create.php" method="POST">
        <table id="tbl">
            <tr>
                <td>Поле раз</td>
                <td>Поле два</td>
                <td>Поле три</td>
                <td>Поле четыре</td>
                <td><a id="addRow">+</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name[]" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="count[]" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="unit[]" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="price[]" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Получаем данные в формате:

```
$_REQUEST['name']
Array
(
    [0] => data1
    [1] => data2
    [2] => data3
)

$_REQUEST['count']
Array
(
    [0] => data1
    [1] => data2
    [2] => data3
)

$_REQUEST['unit']
Array
(
    [0] => data1
    [1] => data2
    [2] => data3
)

$_REQUEST['price']
Array
(
    [0] => data1
    [1] => data2
    [2] => data3
)

$_POST['name']
Array
(
    [0] => data1
    [1] => data2
    [2] => data3
)

$_POST['count']
Array
(
    [0] => data1
    [1] => data2
    [2] => data3
)

$_POST['unit']
Array
(
    [0] => data1
    [1] => data2
    [2] => data3
)

$_POST['price']
Array
(
    [0] => data1
    [1] => data2
    [2] => data3
)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как привести полученные данные к формату:

```
$prods = array(
array(
'name' => 'data1',
'count' => data1,
'unit' => 'data1',
'price' => data1,
'nds' => ,
),
array(
'name' => 'data2',
'count' => data2,
'unit' => 'data2',
'price' => data2,
'nds' => ,
),
array(
'name' => 'data3',
'count' => data3,
'unit' => 'data3',
'price' => data3,
'nds' => ,
),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

я поленился писать  все ваши массивы, дополните там в двух местах, где стоят троеточия

```
function zip() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args as &$x) {
        if(is_string($x)) {
            $x = str_split($x);
        }
        else {
            $x = (array) $x;
        }
    }
    while (True) {
        $r = [];
        foreach($args as &$x) {
            if(! $x) {
                break 2;
            }
            $r[] = array_shift($x);
        }
        yield $r;
    }
}

$prods = [];
foreach(zip($_REQUEST['name'], $_REQUEST['count'], $_REQUEST['unit'],..) as $x) {
   $prods[] = array_combine(['name', 'count', 'unit',..], $x);
}
```